# How to make an installable trigger copy to new spreadsheet copies?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get an installable trigger to run a function every Friday at 9AM. I would like the trigger to carry on to copies of the spreadsheet. I thought I made a trigger on the master spreadsheet but when I look at the "current project's triggers" from the script of the copy, there are no triggers. Am I missing something?

Currently, I have what I think is an installed trigger on the master spreadsheet. The trigger also shows up in "My Triggers".

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: You need to recreate the trigger on the copy as well

Comment: @TheMaster I was reading this post here and I thought it was possible to make a trigger on the master sheet and it would transfer to any copies. Am I misunderstanding something? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990035/how-to-copy-a-google-sheet-and-keep-its-project-triggers-and-scripts

Comment: @RyanCapule I think what that answer means is to use a time trigger(a type of installable trigger) on the master sheet.  The script on that sheet will open each of your copy sheets by it's id. For this, you need to hardcode the ids of your copied sheets and use it in `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`. In any case, triggers don't copy over. Simple triggers however do, since they run automatically as long as a specific function name is present.